# IBM Aspera get size of file before download

Tags: server, download, websphere

I am using Aspera Connect on mac to download files from a server. It works fine in terminal, but i was wondering if before i download a file, i could read its size first and then decide if i want to download it or not. I found the flag 
    `'--precalculate-job-size'`
but it's only doing that right before download and there's no way to stop the download.

The current command i use is this:

`/Applications/Aspera\ Connect.app/Contents/Resources/./ascp -QT -l 200M -P33001 -i "/Applications/Aspera Connect.app/Contents/Resources/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh" emp_ext3@fasp.ebi.ac.uk:/{asp_path} {local_path}`

The resources for the flags are here:

https://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/ascp/2.7/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, without going too much in the details:
If you want to display the size of an elements on an Aspera server for which you have access, you can use the command line "Amelia", see:
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/asperalm

```
mlia server --url=ssh://fasp.ebi.ac.uk:33001 --username=emp_ext3 --ssh-keys=~/.aspera/mlia/aspera_bypass_dsa.pem br /10002/data/100_movie_gc.mrcs
```

there are plenty of options, like : --format=csv --fields=size

Note that this displays individual file sizes, but not recursive folder size.

a few other things:

- You are not exactly using "Connect", but rather the "ascp" command line. Connect refers rather to the browser extension and lightweight app. while ascp is the implementation of Aspera FASP transfer protocol, found basically in all Aspera products.
- the latest ascp documentation can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSL85S_3.9.6/hsts_admin_linux/dita/hsts_admin_linux_ascp_usage.html
- did you know you can also use the free client:
  https://downloads.asperasoft.com/en/downloads/2
  it includes also ascp, but also a graphical user interface